# Tkinter selecting text by index

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, search, tkinter

I am implementing a search function in python with Tkinter and would like to select the first match it comes to. I have seen many examples with creating a tag_config to highlight the background of the indexed range, however I would like to select the text (the same way one would by clicking at the first index, then shift clicking the last index).

Thus far I have got both the start and end index of the area I need to select, I just don't know the command to "select" the text with that information.

My current code (that uses a highlight approach) is:

```
def search_command():

    word = askstring("Search", "Enter word to search")
    length = len(str(word))
    pos = textPad.search(word, '1.0', stopindex=END)
    row, col = pos.split('.')
    endlen = int(col) + length
    end = row + '.' + str(endlen)
    textPad.tag_add("found", pos, end)
```

The "found" tag just highlights the background of the text rather than selecting it.

Any help with finding the correct function would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selection is defined by the `"sel"` tag. Apply that tag to the range of text you want selected:

```
textPad.tag_add("sel", pos, end)
```

Comment: Thank you Bryan, you just made my day. I couldn't find that anywhere!

Comment: @JamesPritchard: it's mentioned here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm and here http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html#selection among other places.